# SpringBoot 2.6.1 incompatibility with Querydsl Mongodb?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I'm upgrading a Java 11 (SpringBoot 2.4.1) application to Java 17 and Spring 2.6.1.

While using SpringBoot 2.4.1, I had these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

`${querydsl.version}` is managed by SpringBoot dependency management.

But when upgrading to SpringBoot 2.6.1 I'm facing this incompatibility:

- `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` brings `mongodb-driver-core/4.4.0`
- `querydsl-mongodb` brings `mongo-java-driver/3.12.8`

And I get this error:

```
The called method's class, com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/SXBN9329/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.4.0/mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/SXBN9329/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.8/mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory and com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings
```

Has somebody any idea to solve that?

Comment: QueryDSL 5 [should support MongoDB 4](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2681). Have you tried excluding the 3.12 driver?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I've tried but it didn't word. I've found the reason, I'm gonna post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason: another module had a dependency to `spring-data-mongodb`. So I had both `spring-data-mongodb` and `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`.

It appears that this doesn't work well with QueryDSL ^^

I've replaced `spring-data-mongodb` by `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` in the other module, and it's working now.